# Sitecore image has "/sitecore/shell" in the path for some images

Tags: c#, sitecore

I use the following code to get the path to an image item in Sitecore

```
Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/',
        HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgMediaItem));
```

For some items, I get the path correct

```
e.g.: -/media/image.jpg
```

For others, it comes back as:
/sitecore/shell/-/media/image.png

What is causing the extra "/sitecore/shell" to be appended to the image path?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the context site (`Sitecore.Context.Site`) is when rendering the media URL. Unfortunately Sitecore takes a lot of required parameters for creating a url from static properties, so depending on what context you're in, you may get different results. This is usually not a problem when rendering regular pages, but it causes issues when building links in for example a background job etc. This issue applies to more areas, such as the LinkManager that also suffers from this.

To solve this, you can provide a `MediaUrlBuilderOptions` argument to the `GetMediaUrl` where you specify needed parameters, such as `Site`.

As an alternatively you can wrap your code in using statements with `SiteContextSwitcher`, `LanguageSwitcher` etc. ensuring your code runs in a context where the static properties has suitable values.

It's also worth noting that this behaviour in Sitecore isn't always bad. Since the `shell` site requires login and uses `master` as content database, it can in some cases be beneficial, for example when reviewing unpublished content.